# Delayed results in flex HTTPService

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, call, httpservice, delay

I've got question about responses via HTTPService in flex.

I send service call to the server in the loop to scale some images, like:

```
while(i < 5)
{
    scaleMyImage({ file: fileArray[i], width: 100, height: 100 }); //this method is going to HTTPService

   i++;
}
```

[Another class]
Then I receive the onResult fine, like

```
onResult($event:ResultEvent):void
{
    trace($event.result) //Hey mister your image is scaled down!
}
```

That works perfect, but I am worried about time between sent call and received response.

Loop sends the files immediately (some small miliseconds between each loop)
callTime: 9.1
callTime: 9.2
callTime: 9.4
callTime: 9.6
callTime: 9.7

but, result gives me response back with delay around second
resultTime: 10.8
resultTime: 11.7
resultTime: 12.9
resultTime: 14.2
resultTime: 15.0

My question is, where is the issue? I thought if I send in the loop 5 calls, server will handle the scaling (it will take around 1,5 second to scale all of them) and then it will give me back immediately in the response 5 messages that the scaling went fine. Is this issue of the Flash, server? or there is no issue at all? and i shouldn't worry about it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Are you worried that the processing of this service request is taking too long? If so, then you'll have to do some time tracking to figure out which aspects of the call are taking longest and see if you can optimize them.  I don't understand what values you're sharing with us; nor how you got them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked this a few days ago, but if you still need to know what's up...

To support concurrent calls... you need to use the MXML version of HTTPService rather than the AS class HTTPService.  The concurrency class rpc.mxml.Concurrency is only imported into the mxml implementation. So use the mx.rpc.http.mxml.HTTPService as a MXML component on your page and it will work as you hoped!